# How to change Thumbnail Caller ID to FullScreen Caller ID with Contacts/Contacts.h

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

[image]

To save the image with the following method the image is always as Thumbnail.

```
            CNMutableContact *updatedContact = [contact mutableCopy];
            NSLog(@"Name Contact: %@ %@", [updatedContact givenName], [updatedContact familyName]);
            NSLog(@"Identifier: %@", [updatedContact identifier]);
            [updatedContact setImageData:[container contactImage]];
            [save updateContact:updatedContact];
            [addressBook executeSaveRequest:save error:&error];
```

Does anyone know how let there as full screen for iOS9 with `CNContactStore`?